# White and Red Chip Combinatorics Problem

Tags: combinatorics

I am doing this problem: A box contains exactly five chips, three red and two white. Chips are randomly removed one at a time without replacement until all the red chips are drawn or all the white chips are drawn. What is the probability that the last chip drawn is white?
What I tried to do is to look at total permutations of the five chips RRRWW which is of course if 5!/(3!2!), the 3! and 2! come from ways to arrange R's and W's as they are identical. Next I set W at the end which represents it being picked last, so there are four slots now so there is 4 ways. This equates to 4/10=2/5. But the answer is 3/5. I don't know what I did wrong. I would appreciate it if someone can point out any mistakes.

Comment: Everything you said is right, but you have interpreted the problem incorrectly. The chips aren't removed until the box becomes empty (which is what you are counting). However, you can rephrase the problem as follows: instead of stopping when one of the colors is depleted, you can keep removing till the box becomes empty. Now, I claim that the color removed last in the original problem is white if and only if the color removed last in the modified problem is red. Do you see why? Once you do this, your argument will show that the answer is $\tfrac{3}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you stop drawing when *either* color is exhausted, white must be exhausted first, which means that a red *must* be at the tail of the queue, directly giving the answer $Pr = \frac35$

If you must use permutations instead (though more complicated),

$\Large\frac{Permutations\; of\; two\; W,\; two\; red}{Permutations\; of\; two\; W,\; three\; R} = \frac{4!}{2!2!}/\frac{5!}{2!3!} = \frac35 $